# How does jailbreaking void the apple warranty when no software as changed?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, warranty

This question has been bugging me for some time.

How does jailbreaking void any apple warranty when no software is changed? Sure, cydia is installed but this dosen't change the operating system in any way.

With android, there is a reason why the warranty can be void, such as:

- Custom recovery flashing
- Custom Operating Systems (e.g Cyanogen Mod (Or Custom ROMS))
- SuperUser
- Modifying the boot screen
- Changing system files

One time I went to my phone store to have my android phone repaired, I said it was rooted, but they still got on with it.

Now take the iOS version of jailbreaking, all you can do is simply change boot screens, probally apply a theme, and thats about it. There are MANY more things but would take too long to type.

And if your iOS device has a problem (e.g wifi not working) Apple support will just be like 'Nope. Sorry can't do it, its jailbroken' and turn it down. Yet all they have to do is just DO A SYSTEM RESTORE. Not many people know how. Thats why if jailbreak is the cause they have to deal with it themselves.

So at the end of this, Why? Why does apple say no jailbroken devices when you cant change the software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I don't feel this question is appropriate for here, there is an article published by Apple on their take of Jailbreaking:

[Apple: Jailbreak](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201954)

Essentially, it IS modified software. A jailbroken OS requires modification to the OS to run - else, you'd just be able to download Cydia and get along with your business. That, in turn, allows unsupported/unapproved software to run on the phone, certain security practices can be avoided, and things of that nature. While it is possible for that to happen through a device that hasn't been rooted, this is their main beef.

Since it's such an unpredictable situation (eg. they can't necessarily say which App caused the WiFi to stop working, or if a system file was modified by the end user, and so on), it's better to err on the side of liability and make the customer assume responsibility for the software restore. That way, they can use approved methods of repair and not get lost down a rabbithole of troubleshooting.

Comment: Apple has *always* been "picky" about what it will cover and not. If you bring a Mac in with 3rd party RAM installed, they will remove it. It's part of the troubleshooting process, "isolate and identify." Remove the variables and if the problem persists then there is a problem. Jailbreaking is a variable and can affect performance and how the phone works. So there are reasonable technical reasons for doing this as well as other reasons that you may disagree with. Life with Apple products has it's annoyances. You have to decide if they are annoyances you can live with.